# How can I center a wide table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, positioning

how can I center my wide table? I already tried everything I could find in different posts. I would be grateful for every tip! My code is attached.

Thanks,

Julia

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,ragged2e, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} 
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Descriptives Table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \textbf{}&\textbf{Mean(SE) or Proportion in \%\tnote{1}}& \textbf{Range} \\
      \toprule
\textbf{Distress} & xxxxx  (0.044) & {0-12} \\
\textbf{Life satisfaction} & xxxxx (0.035) &{0-12} \\
\textbf{Female} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Age} & xxxxx (0.156) & {18-83} \\
\textbf{Overall health} & xxxxx (0.017) & 30-4 \\
\textbf{Low edu. level} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Medium edu. level} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{High edu. level} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Resilience} & xxxxx (0.058) & 3-24 \\
\textbf{Self-esteem} & xxxxx (0.018) & 30-6 \\
\textbf{Time in Germany} & xxxxx (0.02) & {1 mo - 32 yrs} \\
\textbf{Status refugee or asylee} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Status protected} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Status suspension of deport.} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Status awaiting outcome} & 3xxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Status not applicable} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Flight reason} & & \\
\textbf{Negative Experiences} & & \\
\textbf{Not seeking family reunification} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Seeking family reunification } & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Communal accommodation} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Private accommodation w/ other refugees} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Private accommodation w/o other refugees} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Currently not in education} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Currently in education} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Currently not working} & xxxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Currently working} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Not seeking work} & xxxxx\%    &  \\
\textbf{Number of integration courses attended} & xxxxx (0.01) & {0-5} \\
\textbf{Time with others from country o. origin} & xxxxx (0.028) & 31-5 \\
\textbf{Time with Germans} & xxxx (0.028) & 31-5 \\
\textbf{Time with people of other nat. } & xxxx (0.029) & 31-5 \\
\textbf{German lang. ability} & xxxx (0.015) & 30-4 \\
\textbf{No regular leisure activities} & xxxx\%  &  \\
\textbf{Regular leisure activities} & xxxx\%    &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] These values were calculated using weighted and imputed data.
   \end{tablenotes}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of centering, you could restrict the table size to the available text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,ragged2e, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} 
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Descriptives Table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\bfseries}Xll@{}}
    \toprule
    &\textbf{Mean(SE) or}&  \\
    &\textbf{Proportion in \%\tnote{1}}& \textbf{Range} \\
      \midrule
Distress & xxxxx  (0.044) & {0--12} \\
Life satisfaction & xxxxx (0.035) &{0--12} \\
Female & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Age & xxxxx (0.156) & {18--83} \\
Overall health & xxxxx (0.017) & 30--4 \\
Low edu. level & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Medium edu. level & xxxxx\%    &  \\
High edu. level & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Resilience & xxxxx (0.058) & 3--24 \\
Self--esteem & xxxxx (0.018) & 30--6 \\
Time in Germany & xxxxx (0.02) & {1 mo--32 yrs} \\
Status refugee or asylee & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Status protected & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Status suspension of deport. & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Status awaiting outcome & 3xxxx\%  &  \\
Status not applicable & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Flight reason & & \\
Negative Experiences & & \\
Not seeking family reunification & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Seeking family reunification  & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Communal accommodation & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Private accommodation w/ other refugees & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Private accommodation w/o other refugees & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Currently not in education & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Currently in education & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Currently not working & xxxxx\%  &  \\
Currently working & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Not seeking work & xxxxx\%    &  \\
Number of integration courses attended & xxxxx (0.01) & {0--5} \\
Time with others from country o. origin & xxxxx (0.028) & 31--5 \\
Time with Germans & xxxx (0.028) & 31--5 \\
Time with people of other nat.  & xxxx (0.029) & 31--5 \\
German lang. ability & xxxx (0.015) & 30--4 \\
No regular leisure activities & xxxx\%  &  \\
Regular leisure activities & xxxx\%    &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] These values were calculated using weighted and imputed data.
   \end{tablenotes}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice touch to remove all `\textbf` directives from the items in the left-hand column and, instead, to insert a `\bfseries` directive in the definition of the properties of the left-hand column.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works great! Could you explain me the line     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\bfseries}Xll@{}}
please?

Comment: @Julia `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}` is for making the table equal to the available with, `@{}` removes additional spacing around the columns, `>{\raggedright\bfseries}` automatically makes the first column bold and left aligned and `X` is a special column type with linebreaks that uses all the available space.

Comment: @Julia Another suggestion: with the `siunitx` package you could align you numbers.

Comment: @Julia - The `tabularx` package automatically loads the `array` package. The `array` package provides all kinds of nifty tools for modifying the properties of predefined column types. E.g., `>{\raggedright\bfseries}X` means, "apply ragged-right style instead of full justification (the default setting of the `X` column), and automatically typeset the column contents in **bold**". Do read the user guide of the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package to familiarize yourself with the most important tools this package provides.